# How to subtract months from a date and be able to handle overflow?

Tags: c++

I am currently making a C++ library that involves the subtraction of months from a Gregorian calendar date. My add months works but my subtraction formula isn't working and causing errors. Here is the code for my subtraction formula:

```
 Gregorian operator - ( Gregorian const& dt, detail::packaged_month const& month ) {
        year_t yearsToSubtract = month.nMonths_ / 12;
        month_t monthsToSubtract = month.nMonths_ % 12;
        year_t y = dt.year() - yearsToSubtract;
        month_t m = dt.month() - monthsToSubtract;

        int adjustment = ( m - 1 ) / 12 + ( m - 12 ) / 12;
        y -= adjustment;
        m += month_t( adjustment * 12 );

        day_t d = std::min( dt.day(), gregorian_days_in_month( m, is_gregorian_leapyear( y ) ) );

        return Gregorian( y, m, d );
    }
```

The result from this should be if I make a start date of 2001,2,1 or February 1st, 2001 and minus 4 months it should return October 1, 2000 but I am getting an array exception error.

Comment: Is this for learning? Because if not, there are many excellent libraries out there, for example boost date_time: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Comment: Just convert all dates into unix time stamps. Do the subtraction and then convert back. Manual pages/functions are available. If this is too limited then get a different epoch and just reduce it from seconds to days. Write functions to do the same

Comment: This is for learning. I know there is the Boost library, in fact I'm using it to aid with some unit testing of my library and I also tried to look up in the documentation how they did their subtraction of months but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When I use your example and assume that months are 1-12 (and not 0-11) and all values can be turned into ints, I get the following values (at the lines they are declared/modified in your code):

```
yearsToSubtract = 0
monthsToSubtract = 4
y = 2001
m = -2

adjustment = -1
y = 2002
m = -14
```

So assuming I understood it correctly and your debugger backs me up, I'd start at the first line that isn't what you expect it to be and go from there. I expect that line to either be the first `m` or the `adjustment`.